# Loop through Pivot Table dates in VBA 2010

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

Having issues with this problem:
I want to loop through Pivot Table date fields in VBA 2010 so that instead of writing:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivotTable").PivotFields( _
"[Dim Time].[Year Month Day].[Date YYYYMMDD]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
"[Dim Time].[Year Month Day].[Year].&[2015].&[01].&[2015/01/01]", _
"[Dim Time].[Year Month Day].[Year].&[2015].&[01].&[2015/01/02]", _
   "And so on......... until"
"[Dim Time].[Year Month Day].[Year].&[2015].&[01].&[2015/01/19]")`
```

I will write something like

```
Dim Mnths As Integer
Dim Days As Integer
For Mnths = 1 To 5
        For Days = 1 To 19
            Sheets("MtShhet").Select
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivotTable").PivotFields( _
                "[Dim Time].[Year Month Day].[Date YYYYMMDD]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
                "[Dim Time].[Year Month Day].[Year].&[2015].&[" & Mnths & "].&[2015/" & Mnths & "/" & Days & "])"

        Next Days
    Next Mnths
```

I looked around, but most of explanations I saw display different forms of dates not an array as in this example. This weird expression for date as an array I got while recording the Macro. I guess it has something to do with the pivot table creators (not me).

Comment: Do you really want days 1-19 in each of the months for Jan-May, or do you want the whole of Jan-Apr and then the first 19 days of May?

Comment: It might be easier to loop through all the `PivotItems` in the `PivotField` and set `Visible=True/False` to only those items meeting your needs: check `Name`.

Comment: Also, are these all fields in the data or are you using the `Group Field` option on a date?  There are some oddities with how grouped items are named. You can expect difficulties trying to match the day names since they are formatted as `DAY-MON` or `dd-mmm`.  And, finally I think the months are set using `MON` or `mmm` format.  Of course, if these are your own items then that's all a moot point.

Comment: @Rory - yes I want days 1-19 in each of the months for Jan-May... Any ideas?

Comment: @Byron Yeah I know that the pivot is strange. The field named "Year Month Day" but I'm not able to use the conventional date format on it

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test the final part, but you can build up the array like this:

```
Dim Mnths                 As Integer
Dim Days                  As Integer
Dim vDates(1 To 95)

Const csDIMENSION         As String = "[Dim Time].[Year Month Day].[Year].&[2015].&["
For Mnths = 1 To 5
    For Days = 1 To 19
        vDates((Mnths - 1) * 19 + Days) = csDIMENSION & Mnths & "].&[2015/" & Format$(Mnths, "00") & "/" & Format$(Days, "00") & "])"
    Next Days
Next Mnths
Sheets("MtShhet").PivotTables("MyPivotTable").PivotFields("[Dim Time].[Year Month Day].[Date YYYYMMDD]").VisibleItemsList = vDates
```